# Stylesheet parsing error for [dir=rtl] when using cssutils python module

Tags: python, html, css, css-selectors, css-parsing

I'm parsing a css stylesheet with [cssutils](http://code.google.com/p/cssutils/) python module.
The parser emits an error when reaching the "[dir=ltr] div.row div.label" selector.

I would like to find a way to modify the CSS to make the parser happy and maintain the same functionality.

What would be the standard way for this:

```
div.row div.label {
 float: left;
 width: 18%;
 text-align: right;
}
div.row div.formw {
 width: 80%;
}
[dir=ltr] div.row div.label, [dir=rtl] div.row div.formw {
 float: left;
 text-align: right;
}
[dir=rtl] div.row div.label, [dir=ltr] div.row div.formw {
 float: right;
 text-align: left;
}
```

Note: 
"dir" is used to control the direction of the text for languages like hebrew or arabic.

[http://www.unics.uni-hannover.de/nhtcapri/bidirectional-text.html](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-css-markup.es.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's a bit slower but

```
*[dir=ltr] div.row div.label, *[dir=rtl] div.row div.formw {
 float: left;
 text-align: right;
}
*[dir=rtl] div.row div.label, *[dir=ltr] div.row div.formw {
 float: right;
 text-align: left;
}
```

should work. Obviously change * with the element with this attribute if is possible

Comment: It seems it works for now. It parses it now and doesn't ignore the selector. Thanks!

Comment: `[dir=ltr]` and `*[dir=ltr]` are identical selectors - the only performance downside is the addition of the `*` character, and if you're working with a parser alone there's seriously nothing to worry about.